# What do we call JS async "strands of execution"?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous

In Java we have "threads", in CPython we have threads (non-concurrent) and "processes".

In JS, when I kick off an `async` function or method, how do I officially refer to these "strands of executing code"?

I have heard that each such code block executes from start to finish*, meaning that there is never any concurrent** processing in JS.  I'm not quite sure whether this is the same situation as with CPython threads.  Personally I hesitate to use "thread" for what we have in JS as these "strands" are so different from Java concurrent threads.

---

* Just to clarify in light of Stephen Cleary's helpful response: I mean "each such ***synchronous*** code block".  Obviously if an `await` is encountered control is released ...

** And obviously never any "true parallel" processing. I'm following the widely accepted distinction between "concurrent" (only one thread at any one time, but one "strand of execution" may give way to another) and "parallel" (multiple processes, implementing true parallel processing, often using multiple CPUs or cores or processes).  My understanding is that these "strands" in JS are not even concurrent: once one AJAX method or `Promise` or `async` method/function starts executing nothing can happen until it's finished (or an `await` happens)...

Comment: I have never heard this term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date 24 people, no more no fewer, have chosen to look at this.

FWIW, and should anyone eccentric take an interest in this question one day, I propose "hogging strands" or just "strands" ... they *hog* the browser's JS engine, it would appear, and just don't let go, unless they encounter an `await`.

I've been developing this app where 3 "strands" operate more or less simultaneously, all involving AJAX calls and a database query... but in fact it is highly preferable if the 2nd of the 3 executes and returns before the 3rd.

But because the 3rd query is quite a bit simpler for MySQL than the 2nd the former tends to return from its AJAX "excursion" quite a bit earlier if everything is allowed to operate with unconstrained asynchronicity. This then causes a big delay before the 2nd strand is allowed to do its stuff.  To force the code to perform and complete the 2nd "strand" therefore requires quite a bit of coercion, using `async` and `await`.

I read one comment on JS asynchronicity somewhere where someone opined that the way things operate in JS means you "never have to worry about concurrency issues, etc.". I don't agree: if you don't in fact know when `await`s will unblock this does necessarily mean that concurrency is involved.  Perhaps "hogging strands" are easier to deal with than true "concurrency", let alone true "parallelism", however... ?

Answer (score 1):

> In JS, when I kick off an async function or method, how do I officially refer to these "strands of executing code"?

For lack of a better term, I've referred to these as "asynchronous operations".

> I have heard that each such code block executes from start to finish

This **was** true... until `await`. Now there's a couple of ways to think about it, both of which are correct:

- Code blocks execute exclusively *unless* there's an `await`.
- `await` splits its function into multiple code blocks that *do* execute exclusively (each `await` is a "split point").

> meaning that there is never any concurrent processing in JS.

I'd disagree with this statement. JavaScript forces asynchrony (before `async`/`await`, it used callbacks or promises), so it does have asynchronous concurrency, though not parallel concurrency.

A good mental model is that JavaScript is inherently single-threaded, and that one thread has a queue of work to do. `await` does not block that thread; it *returns*, and when its thenable/Promise completes, it schedules the remainder of that method (the "continuation") to the queue.

So you can have multiple asynchronous methods executing concurrently. This is exactly how Node.js handles multiple simultaneous requests.

> My understanding is that these "strands" in JS are not even concurrent: once one AJAX method or Promise or async method/function starts executing nothing can happen until it's finished...

No, this is incorrect. `await` will return control to the main thread, freeing it up to do other work.

> the way things operate in JS means you "never have to worry about concurrency issues, etc."

Well... yes and no. Since JavaScript is inherently single-threaded, there's never any contention over data shared between multiple threads (obviously). I'd say that's what the original writer was thinking about. So I'd say easily north of 90% of thread-synchronization problems do just go away.

However, as you noted, you still need to be careful modifying shared state from multiple asynchronous operations. If they're running concurrently, then they can complete in any order, and your logic has to properly handle that.

Ideally, the best solution is to move to a more functional mindset - that is, get rid of the shared state as much as possible. Asynchronous operations should *return* their results instead of updating shared state. Then these concurrent asynchronous operations can be composed into a higher-level asynchronous operation using `async`, `await`, and `Promise.all`. If possible, this more functional approach of returning-instead-of-state and function composition will make the code easier to deal with.

But there's still some situations where this isn't easily achievable. It's possible to develop asynchronous equivalents of classical synchronous coordination primitives. I worked up a proof-of-concept AsyncLock, but can't seem to find the code anywhere. Well, it's *possible* to do this, anyway.

Comment: Er... yes, my understanding is exactly the same as yours. My comment about "concurrency not an issue" was quoting someone else and saying they are wrong.  Of course `await` hands control back to the JS engine and allows another strand to continue.  When you say "this is incorrect", this is a misunderstanding of the point I was making: all ***synchronous*** code in JS "hogs" the JS engine.  This is why I say it is not even "concurrent" in the true sense: the JS engine cannot do anything but process a synchrous code strand until that strand stops "hogging", possibly due to an `await`.

Comment: Contrast this with CPython where, although the interpreter is not capable of achieving parallelism (within the same process) it is, I believe, capable of switching from processing one **thread** to another without an explicit cue in the code (i.e. `await`)... which, in my eyes, thus qualifies as true concurrency.  Unlike JS. And which is why you can have shared state in CPython which you have to worry about a lot more than in JS!

Comment: So you're really talking about preemption (or lack thereof).

Comment: Yes, indeed.  My understanding (such as it is) is that CPython implements it and JS doesn't.  But let's not split hairs :) the question was just about "what shall we call these strands of execution?", not some casuistry about whether they represent true concurrency...!